# Embedding dynamic images in Tableau Dashboard

Tags: image, dynamic, tableau-api

I am new to Tableau. I am currently working on a dashboard where I should be able to click on an ID in the Dashboard and it opens a link with the image corresponding to that ID.

For example, I click on ID 5 and the link will be -

https://xxx.xxx.xx.com/xx/xx/id=5.

If I click on ID 10 the link will be -

https://xxx.xxx.xx.com/xx/xx/id=10.

So I have 2 questions to do this in Tableau-

1) How do I dynamically insert the ID part every time I click on the ID ?

2) Once I can able to click on a particular ID, how do I display this webpage in the same Dashboard without breaking even after publishing it ?

Thanks in advance :) :)

Answer (score 0):

**URL ACTION**

URL action is the solution for such scenario

1 click on Edit|Actions,

2 select “URL action” from the actions dialog

3 assign a name to the action

4 click on “Run action on Select”

More details are at below link
http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2010/08/the-power-of-tableau-actions.html

Comment: Thanks Sandeep :).. I have already seen this link.... Didn't feel much insightful in terms of explaining this topic. Could you please share if you have any other resource which is more straight forward. Thanks once again for your help. :)